# MYSQL UPDATE is creating new record

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

As the Title says. When I am calling the `UPDATE` method in mysql, It Does update the cell. But creates a new row with the old data.

Here is the stored procedure Im using:

```
Procedure [dbo].[Insert_Invoice_And_Insert_Address]
@UserID int,
@Occasion nvarchar(50),
@FlowerName nvarchar(50),
@FirstName nvarchar(50),
@LastName nvarchar(50),
@StreetAddress nvarchar(50),
@Suite nvarchar(50),
@City nvarchar(50),
@Country nvarchar(50),
@Province nvarchar(50),
@PostalCode nvarchar(50)
as
DECLARE @TaxCode money
DECLARE @InvoiceID int
DECLARE @FlowerID int
DECLARE @AddressID int
DECLARE @CountryID int
DECLARE @ProvinceID int


SET @TaxCode = (SELECT [TaxRate]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[TaxCode]
                where [Status] like 1)
                SELECT @TaxCode;

SET @CountryID = (SELECT [CountryID]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Country]
                WHERE [DisplayValue] like @Country)
                SELECT @CountryID

SET @ProvinceID = (SELECT [ProvinceID]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Province]
                WHERE [Name] Like @Province)
                SELECT @ProvinceID

SET @FlowerID = (SELECT [FlowerID]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Flowers]
                where [Description] like @FlowerName)
                SELECT @FlowerID;

IF @FlowerID in (SELECT [Flower]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                WHERE [Processed] = 0 and [InvoiceID] = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                                    FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                                    WHERE [UserID] = @UserID and [Processed] = 0)) BEGIN
                SET @InvoiceID = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                    FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                    where [UserID] like @UserID and [Processed] like 0);
                    SELECT @InvoiceID;
                UPDATE [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                    SET [ItemNumber] = [ItemNumber] + 1
                    WHERE InvoiceID like @InvoiceID and [Processed] like 0 and Flower like @FlowerID;
                END
                ELSE
INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
            ([UserID]
            ,[TaxCode]
            ,[Processed]
            )
        VALUES
            (@UserID
            ,@TaxCode
            ,0
            )

INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[Addresses]
            ([Street]
            ,[apt]
            ,[City]
            ,[Province]
            ,[Country]
            ,[PostalCode]
            )
            VALUES
            (@StreetAddress
            ,@Suite
            ,@City
            ,@ProvinceID
            ,@CountryID
            ,@PostalCode
            )

SET @AddressID = (SELECT [AddressID]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Addresses]
                where [PostalCode] like @PostalCode and [Street] like @StreetAddress)
                SELECT @AddressID;

SET @InvoiceID = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                where [UserID] like @UserID and [Processed] like 0);
                SELECT @InvoiceID;

INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
            ([ItemNumber]
            ,[Flower]
            ,[Processed]
            ,[DeliveryAddress]
            ,[InvoiceID]
            )
        VALUES
            (1
            ,@FlowerID
            ,0
            ,@AddressID
            ,@InvoiceID
            )
```

What it is used for is a order page. and in order to add more quantity to your basket, you end up just sending the info like its you first order. And I use the IF ELSE statements to determine if this is a first order, Or if its adding more quantity.
incase you're wondering why its being done like that. its A school project. And they specifically asked for it to be done like this.

EDIT:

Here is the snipet of code im having issues with:

```
UPDATE [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                    SET [ItemNumber] = [ItemNumber] + 1
                    WHERE InvoiceID like @InvoiceID and [Processed] like 0 and Flower like @FlowerID;
```

Comment: Could you tell which statements should be executed on `ELSE` condition?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Where is done the `UPDATE` in this stored procedure?

Comment: This is SQL Server right?

Comment: @user2941651 The else condition will input all the information into the 3 following tables: Invoice, InvoiceDetails and Address. iit also links them all using IDs

Comment: @wchiquito SQL Server. I added a snippet of the update code into the main post

Comment: @IvanCachicatari SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this modification in your script (you've missed your BEGIN .. END in your else block (the 3 statements):

```
(...)

IF @FlowerID in (SELECT [Flower]
                    FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                    WHERE [Processed] = 0 and [InvoiceID] = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                                        FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                                        WHERE [UserID] = @UserID and [Processed] = 0)) 
    BEGIN
                    SET @InvoiceID = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                        FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                        where [UserID] like @UserID and [Processed] like 0);
                        SELECT @InvoiceID;
                    UPDATE [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                        SET [ItemNumber] = [ItemNumber] + 1
                        WHERE InvoiceID like @InvoiceID and [Processed] like 0 and Flower like @FlowerID;
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                ([UserID]
                ,[TaxCode]
                ,[Processed]
                )
            VALUES
                (@UserID
                ,@TaxCode
                ,0
                )

    INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[Addresses]
                ([Street]
                ,[apt]
                ,[City]
                ,[Province]
                ,[Country]
                ,[PostalCode]
                )
                VALUES
                (@StreetAddress
                ,@Suite
                ,@City
                ,@ProvinceID
                ,@CountryID
                ,@PostalCode
                )

    SET @AddressID = (SELECT [AddressID]
                    FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Addresses]
                    where [PostalCode] like @PostalCode and [Street] like @StreetAddress)
                    SELECT @AddressID;

    SET @InvoiceID = (SELECT [InvoiceID]
                    FROM [Flowers].[dbo].[Invoices]
                    where [UserID] like @UserID and [Processed] like 0);
                    SELECT @InvoiceID;

    INSERT INTO [Flowers].[dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
                ([ItemNumber]
                ,[Flower]
                ,[Processed]
                ,[DeliveryAddress]
                ,[InvoiceID]
                )
            VALUES
                (1
                ,@FlowerID
                ,0
                ,@AddressID
                ,@InvoiceID
                )
    END
```

Comment: Awesome. it works.

just commenting to let people Know I had to change the "like" statements to "=" statements where I was setting the variables. the "Like" in the @ProvinceID was returning null. where the "=" returned results

Comment: I'm really glad that the solution was found plus the mistakes noticed by yourself. So let's go on learning :) Regards.